# Compiling cpp-ethereum (aleth) sources as a part of my cpp project

Tags: cpp-ethereum, compilation, build-from-source

I want to use cpp-ethereum [aleth](https://github.com/ethereum/aleth) smart contracts sources in my altcoin project. My sources can compile with cmake or autotools system. I tried two ways to compile cpp-ethereum with my sources:

1. Using cmake build system, I had added aleth as git submodules, then in my CMakeLists.txt putted this command
   add_subdirectory(src/cpp-ethereum)
   and then received an error:

CMake Error at src/cpp-ethereum/CMakeLists.txt:8 (message):
  Git submodules not initialized, execute:

```
git submodule update --init
```

So, I understood that CMakeLists.txt in aleth sources designed for stand alone compiling...

2. Using autotools build system: I had put all dependencies, cpp-ethereum (aleth) sources into my project dir. Put all paths into Makefile.am and configure.ac scripts, but during compile received dependencies sources errors: 
   [image]

Please, give me some instructions how can I compile my sources (no matter, with using autotools or cmake, but will be better with cmake of course) with cpp-ethereum sources with all dependencies in a single binary. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Adding --enable-module-ecdh in configure.ac and crypto++ 5.65 sources resolved a problem for autotools build. But, maybe can anyone to know how to do it with cmake?